Tikz learning resources
Been putting off learning Tikz and CircuitTikz for a while now. Tried using some GUI's to design my diagrams but frankly none of them are very useful (clunky, missing tons of features etc.) I'm not looking to do complex things, but I'd like to at least learn enough to get a good grasp on the package. Is the best thing to use the tikz.dev website or does someone have any other great resources that helped them learn pretty quickly (YouTube playlist, online tut?). Many thanks.

Welcome to tex.sx.

Welcome. // Wrt tikz I suggest scanning the tutorials in the beginning. This will give you a first idea about the syntax. // Though circuitikz builds on tikz, you most likely can use it standalone. I.e. read its manual, try some code, scan some Q&A here. // To my experience videos tend to be a waste of time. While you evaluate them, you could have read the cicuitikz manual and compiled some circuits, perhaps posted a question here or two. The author is very active here and helpful. // For google enter: ctan circuitikz

It’s always a good idea to inspect this sites tags: https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/circuitikz/info provides 2 answers to you.

Look into the online manual of TikZ. It has great tutorials.

A set of short tutorials embedded in the official super-long manual:

https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf

From the official repository and Web page: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf



Sets of examples:

https://tikz.net/topics/
https://tikz.dev/
https://texample.net//tikz/examples/
https://tikz.org/
Additional lists at: https://tikz.org/websites/

Basic tutorials:

https://uva-fnwi.github.io/LaTeX/extra1/Tikz/
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ%3A_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_1)%E2%80%94Basic_Drawing


Nice :) Did you find similar sources on circuitikz, besides teh ones mentioned in its tag? (like on Overleaf: https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ%3A_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_4)%E2%80%94Circuit_Diagrams_Using_Circuitikz)

Not yet, @MS-SPO...
